# Distance From Center Of Circle To Intersection Of Diagonals Of A Cyclic Quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given a cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ with length $AB=w$, $BC=x$, $CD=y$, and $DA=z$, compute the distance from the center of the circumscribing circle to the intersection point of the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ in terms of $w,x,y,z$.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you draw a figure?

Comment: I did draw a figure as an example (a quadrilateral with side lengths 2,3,4,5, and the circumscribing circle), but that didn’t get me anywhere.

Comment: Consider the degenerate case, that one of $w,x,y,z$ equals zero. In this case you actually have a triangle and the intersection degenerates as one of the vertex. So the distance you are saying becomes the radius of the circumcircle. Do you know how to write down an explicit formula in this special case? This should at least give you a feeling how complicated the formula you are asking for should be (which I do not know what it is at this moment).

Comment: Find the circle center and the intersection of diagonals independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [@dan_fulea's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3302875/409), I'll take the sides of the cyclic quadrilateral $\square ABCD$ to be $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ (in order). Let the diagonals be $p$ and $q$ (either order). Let the diagonals meet at $L$, let their midpoints be $M$ and $N$ (either order), and let the circumcenter be $O$.

Each diagonal is a chord of the circle; therefore, it's perpendicular to the segment joining its midpoint to $O$. Consequently, $\square OMLN$ has an opposite pair of right angles, making it cyclic; moreover, its circumdiameter is exactly $|OL|$, the distance we seek. By the (Extended) Law of Sines and the area formula $|\square ABCD|=\tfrac12pq\sin\angle MLN$ (valid for any quadrilateral), we can write

> $$|OL| = \frac{|MN|}{\sin\angle MLN} = \frac{p q \;|MN|}{2\;|\square ABCD|} \tag{$\star$}$$

From here, we proceed as @dan did, leveraging existing results to get expressions for substitution into $(\star)$.

---

[Euler's (not-necessarily-cyclic) Quadrilateral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_quadrilateral_theorem) states that
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = p^2 + q^2 + 4 |MN|^2 \tag{1}$$
and it is ["known"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral#Diagonals) that the diagonals of a cyclic quadrilateral satisfy
$$p^2 + q^2 = \frac{(ac+bd)(ad+bc)}{ab+cd}+\frac{(ac+bd)(ab+cd)}{ad+bc} \qquad\qquad
pq = ac+bd \tag{2}$$
(the latter of which is [Ptolemy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem)). Finally, [Brahmagupta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_formula) for the area of a cyclic quadrilateral gives
$$|\square ABCD|^2 = (s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d) \tag{3}$$
where $s:=\tfrac12(a+b+c+d)$ is the semiperimeter of $\square ABCD$.

Substituting $p^2+q^2$ from $(2)$ into $(1)$, and solving, we get
$$|MN|^2 = \frac{ac(b^2-d^2)^2+bd(a^2-c^2)^2}{4(ab+cd)(ad+bc)} \tag{4}$$

Therefore, squaring to avoid radicals, $(\star)$ becomes ...

> $$|OL|^2 = \frac{1}{16}\;\frac{ac(b^2-d^2)^2+bd(a^2-c^2)^2}{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)}\;\frac{(ac+bd)^2}{(ab+cd)(ad+bc)} \tag{$\star\star$}$$

... which agrees with @dan's solution. $\square$

Answer (score 2):

I will use picture and the notations from

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral

so the cyclic quadrilateral under study is $ABCD$, it sides are $AB=a$, $BC=b$, $CD=c$, $DA=d$ (instead of $w,x,y,z$, which i cannot type in this context without error.)

The intersection of the diagonals is $P$, and the center of the circle $(ABCD)$ is $O$, we denote by $R$ the radius $R=OA=OB=OC=OD$.
When two letters are used in connection with metric relation, we mean always the corresponding lengths.

---

We will use the following facts and solve the issue:

[image: Computing the distance from center of cyclic quadrilateral to intersection of diagonals]

- The power of the interior point $P$ is 
  $$PA\cdot PC=PB\cdot PD=R^2-OP^2\ .$$
- The relations of Brahmagupta and Parameshvara, and similar relations for the trigonometric functions of the angles in $A,B,C,D$, and of the angle $\theta$ between the diagonals.
- The sine theorem, for instance 
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \frac{PA}{DA}
  &=
  \frac
  {\sin \widehat{PDA}}
  {\sin \widehat{APD}}
  =
  \frac
  {\sin \widehat{BDA}}
  {\sin \theta}
  =
  \frac
  {\sin \frac 12\widehat{BOA}}
  {\sin \theta}
  =
  \frac {\frac{AB/2}R}
  {\sin \theta}\ ,
  \\[2mm]
  &\qquad
  \text{ which implies}
  \\[2mm]
  PA 
  &= \frac{AD\cdot AB}{2R\sin\theta}
  = \frac{da}{2R\sin\theta}
  \ ,\qquad\text{ and similarly}
  \\
  PC &= \frac{CD\cdot CB}{2R\sin\theta}
  = \frac{cb}{2R\sin\theta}
  \ .
  \end{aligned}
  $$

---

We are now in position to join the following relations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
R^2-OP^2
&=
PA\cdot PC
=\frac {abcd}{4R^2\sin^2\theta}\ ,
\\
4R^2 
&=
\frac 14\cdot
\frac
{(ab+cd)(ac+bd)(ad+bc)}
{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)}\text{ (Parameshvara) with }
\\
s&=\frac 12(a+b+c+d)\ ,
\\[2mm]
&\qquad\text{ and we use now}
\\
\tan^2\frac\theta 2
&=
\frac{(s-b)(s-d)}{(s-a)(s-c)}\text{ to compute}
\\
\frac1{\cos^2\frac\theta 2}
&=
1+
\tan^2\frac\theta 2
=
\frac{(s-a)(s-c)+(s-b)(s-d)}{(s-a)(s-c)}
\sin^2\theta
\\
\cos^2\frac\theta 2
&=
\frac
{(s-a)(s-c)}
{(s-a)(s-c)+(s-b)(s-d)}
\\
\sin^2\frac\theta 2
&=
\frac
{(s-b)(s-d)}
{(s-a)(s-c)+(s-b)(s-d)}
\\
\sin^2\theta &= 
4
\sin^2\frac\theta 2
\cos^2\frac\theta 2
\\
&=
4\cdot
\frac
{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)}
{(\; (s-a)(s-c)+(s-b)(s-d)\;)^2}\ ,
\\
4R^2\sin^2\theta
&=
\frac
{(ab+cd)(ac+bd)(ad+bc)}
{(\;(s-a)(s-c)+(s-b)(s-d)\;)^2}\ ,
\\
PA\cdot PC
&=\frac {abcd}{4R^2\sin^2\theta}
=
\frac
{abcd\;(\;(s-a)(s-c)+(s-b)(s-d)\;)^2}
{(ab+cd)(ac+bd)(ad+bc)}
\ ,\\[2mm]
&\qquad\text{ and finally}
\\
\color{blue}
{OP^2}
&=
R^2-PA\cdot PC
\\
&=
\color{blue}
{
\frac 1{16}
\cdot
\frac 1{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)}
\cdot
\frac
{(ac+bd)^2}
{(ab+cd)(ad+bc)}
\cdot
\Big(\ 
bd(a^2-c^2)^2+ac(b^2-d^2)^2
\ \Big)
}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Note:
At the last step we have used [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) to factorize. Code and results:

```
sage: S.<a,b,c,d> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
sage: RR = 1/16 * (a*c+b*d)*(a*b+c*d)*(a*d+b*c) / (s-a) / (s-b) / (s-c) / (s-d)
sage: PAPC = a*b*c*d * ((s-a)*(s-c)+(s-b)*(s-d))^2 / (  (a*c+b*d)*(a*b+c*d)*(a*d+b*c) )
sage: factor( RR - PAPC )
-(a*b^4*c + a^4*b*d - 2*a^2*b*c^2*d + b*c^4*d 
                    - 2*a*b^2*c*d^2 + a*c*d^4)
* (a*c + b*d)^2
/ ((a*b + c*d)*(b*c + a*d)
  *(a + b + c - d)
  *(a + b - c + d)
  *(a - b + c + d)
  *(a - b - c - d))
```

(Lines were manually broken.)